# Is there a way to get correlation with string data and a numerical value in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get a correlation in pandas that's giving me a bit of difficulty. Essentially I want to answer the following question: given a sentence and a value and a dataframe, what word correlates the best with a higher value? What about the worst?

Trivial example:

```
Sentence      | Score
"hello there" | 100
"hello kid"   | 95
"there kid"   | 5
```

I'm expecting to see a high correlation value here for the word "hello" and score.  Hopefully this makes sense -- if this is possible natively in Pandas I'd really appreciate knowing!

If anything is unclear please let me know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure that `pandas` is what you looking for, but yes, you can:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([ ["hello there", 100],
                    ["hello kid",   95],
                    ["there kid",   5]
                  ], columns = ['Sentence','Score'])

s_corr = df.Sentence.str.get_dummies(sep=' ').corrwith(df.Score/df.Score.max())
print (s_corr)
```

Will return you

```
hello    0.998906
kid     -0.539949
there   -0.458957
```

for details see `pandas` help

1. [`str.get_dummies()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html)
2. [`corrwith()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.corrwith.html)

Comment: Thanks, this looks great. You said pandas might not be what I'm looking for -- is there a different library you'd recommend? I was using pandas because a) I want to get better at it and b) it's what the data is in now.

Comment: In my understanding, `pandas` is  the great in-memory  RDBMS with benefits. Using that benefits I can answer exactly your question with oneliner - it is funny and very helpful for exploration. But in real world you will have a lot of problems with that implementation.   
Starting with memory consumption of a huge sparse matrix generated by `str.get_dummies` known as Bag of Words (BoW) with shape of samples*dictionary of all dataset.

Comment: On next steps you will find that some words (like 'the', 'a', 'is') are meaningless frequent and you'll need to remove them or adjust their weight with TF-IDF transformation and so on. All this is a part of Natural Language Processing (NLP) so I recommend you to use specialized NLP library like [ntlk](http://www.nltk.org/) if you going into text deep analysis.  In case you are going to predict scores based on text and other factors take a look on ML framework [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html) it supports all the basics of NLP.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way. Take the average score for each occurrence of the word in each string. For example "hello" receives 97.5, "there" receives 52.5 [(100 + 5) / 2], etc.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Score': {0: 100, 1: 95, 2: 5},
                             'Sentence': {0: 'hello there', 1: 'hello kid', 2: 'there kid'}})

df['WordList'] = df['Sentence'].str.split(' ')

d = defaultdict(list)

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    for word in row['WordList']:
        d[word].append(row['Score'])

d = {k: np.mean(v) for k, v in d.items()}

{'hello': 97.5, 'there': 52.5, 'kid': 50.0}
```