# Calculate correlation between columns of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string, correlation

I've got a df that contains the columns profession and media. I would like to calculate the correlation between those two columns.

Is there a short hack of calculating the correlation of columns of strings? Or do I have transform each profession and media to a number and then calculate the correlation with .corr()?

I found a similar question ([Is there a way to get correlation with string data and a numerical value in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48873233/is-there-a-way-to-get-correlation-with-string-data-and-a-numerical-value-in-pand)) but I would like to check the string, not each word within the string.

```
df

  profession        media      

0 media lawyer      print
1 student           online
2 student           print
3 professor         online
4 media lawyer      online
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can convert datatype to categorical and then do it

```
df['profession']=df['profession'].astype('category').cat.codes
df['media']=df['media'].astype('category').cat.codes
df.corr()
```

Comment: Can you provide some explanation to this answer. It works fine. it's just that I wanna know why .cat.codes. And what does .codes do?

Comment: `.cat.codes` converts your category from a string representation into an integer representation. For example, `media lawyer` would be replaced with 0, `student` would be replaced with 1, `professor` would be replaced with 2. In the other column, `print` would be replaced with 0 and `online` would be replaced with 1

Comment: Does this makes sense? Because if we have more than 2 values of strings, this can make 3 categories of 0, 1 and 2, and it might interpret that 2 is farther from 0 than 1... Not sure if I made myself clear.

Answer (score 2):

As [@JAgustinBarrachina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5931672/j-agustin-barrachina) pointed out, the accepted answer introduces a bias because it uses the Pearson correlation method under the hood.
The categorization of each column may produce the following:

- media lawyer --> 0
- student --> 1
- Professor --> 2

Because the Pearson method computes linear correlation, it will compute the distance between each category. From the algorithm point of view a `media lawyer` will be more different from a `professor` (their distance is 2 - 0 = 2) than it will be different from a `student` ( 1 - 0 = 1). That is not true in this case so the resulting correlation would be biased.

[From the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html) 2 other correlation methods are available : The Kendall and the Spearman methods. But they both suppose an the categories are ordered.
For example a category such as `revenue : ["low", "medium", "high"]` could be considered as ordered.

If there is no order between the categories of a column, a method using Chi² and Cramér's V is more appropriate:

```py
import scipy.stats as ss
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, Series

profession_and_media = DataFrame(data = {
    # Decupling data to simulate significance
    "profession" : ["media lawyer" , "student" , "student" , "professor" , "media lawyer"] * 10,
    "media" : ["print" , "online" , "print" , "online" , "online"] * 10
    })

def cramers_corrected_stat(columnA: Series, columnB: Series):
    """ calculate Cramers V statistic for categorial-categorial association.
        uses correction from Bergsma and Wicher, 
        Journal of the Korean Statistical Society 42 (2013): 323-328
    """
    confusion_matrix = pd.crosstab(columnA, columnB)
    chi2 = ss.chi2_contingency(confusion_matrix)[0]
    n = confusion_matrix.to_numpy().sum(axis=None)
    phi2 = chi2/n
    r,k = confusion_matrix.shape
    phi2corr = max(0, phi2 - ((k-1)*(r-1))/(n-1))    
    rcorr = r - ((r-1)**2)/(n-1)
    kcorr = k - ((k-1)**2)/(n-1)
    return np.sqrt(phi2corr / min( (kcorr-1), (rcorr-1)))


def compute_category_correlation(df: DataFrame):
    """ Compute the correlation between string columns of a DataFrame
    """
    for column in df.columns:
        df.loc[:, column] = df[column].astype('category').cat.codes
    result = df.corr(method=cramers_corrected_stat)
    return result.style.background_gradient(cmap='Reds')

compute_category_correlation(profession_and_media)
```

Which gives
[image: Correlation matrix between profession and media]