# How to find the correlation between two strings in pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, correlation

I have df of string values

```
   Keyword
    plant
    cell
    cat
    Pandas
```

And I want to find the relationship or correlation between these two string values.

I have used pandas `corr = df1.corrwith(df2,axis=0)`.
But this is useful for to find the correlation between the numerical values but I want to see whether the two strings are related by finding the correlation distance. How can I do that?

Comment: are you intended to find correlation of letters or word synonym distance ?

Comment: @NagaKiran Synonym distance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate correlation between columns of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51241575/calculate-correlation-between-columns-of-strings)

Comment: @Georgy No i want to find synonym distance but between plant&cell,plant&cat,plant&Pandas etc to see how much synonym distance is present and not one correlation value i want individual scores

Comment: You ca refer the link [Semantic feature generation](https://github.com/Nagakiran1/Semantic-Feature-generation-for-words)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few steps here, the first thing you need to do is extract some sort of vector for each word.

A good way is using gensim word2vec (you need to download the files from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7XkCwpI5KDYNlNUTTlSS21pQmM/edit)):

```
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors

model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('data/GoogleGoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True)
```

after getting the pretrained vectors you need to extract the vector for each word:

```
vector = model['plant']
```

or in the pandas column example:

```
df['Vectors'] = df['Keyword'].apply(lambda x: model[x])
```

Once this is done you can calculate the distance between two vectors using a number of methodologies, eg euclidean distance:

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances
distances = euclidean_distances(list(df['Vectors']))
```

distances will be a matrix, with 0 on the diagonal and the distance of all words from each other. The closer a distance is to 0, the more similar the words are.

You can use different models and different distance metrics, but you can use this as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

More often than not, the above approach of loading the model may not work so I am sharing with you the approach that worked for me. I am using Google Colab therefore the use of '!' before each command.

Download the file(i.e. the model) using `wget` like so:

```
!wget -c "https://s3.amazonaws.com/dl4j-distribution/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz"
```

Next use `gzip` to unzip the file using this command:

```
!gzip -d GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz
```

Next up use the `models` library from `gensim` to load the downloaded file using this code. This will give you the `wordVector` model for further use. I am using Google Colab so the file path can change if you are doing the process locally:

```
from gensim import models
model = models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(
    '/content/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True)
```