# Calculating correlation of two text columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, data-science

I'm good in Python but new to Pandas and know almost nothing about stats so forgive me if this is a simple or ignorant question.

Say I have a dataframe with two columns like, e.g., `Jobs` and `Cars` where the entries in both are one of a finite set of strings, e.g. `[Software Engineer, Sysadmin, Product Manager]` and `[Tesla, Hummer, Ford Focus]`.

I want to produce a table of some sort showing the correlation between jobs and cars, like this:

```
|     | Tesla | Hummer | Ford Focus |
| SWE | ###   | ###    | ###        |
| SA  | ###   | ###    | ###        |
| PM  | ###   | ###    | ###        |
```

What's the most pythonic way of doing this? Honestly this is a one off query and my data set is pretty small so it doesn't need to be the most efficient.

Edit: A sample dataframe could be generated like this

```
from random import choice

jobs = ['SWE', 'Data Scientist', 'Product Manager', 'Sysadmin', 'Data Engineer']
cars = ['Tesla', 'Hummer', 'Ford Focus', 'Chevy Volt', 'Toyota Tercel']

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'jobs': [choice(jobs) for _ in range(1000) ], 
    'cars': [choice(cars) for _ in range(1000) ]
})
```

The expected output would be similar to that of `DataFrame.corr()` but that function only operates on numbers and these are strings.

Comment: I edited the question with a sample and expected output

Comment: Ownership of the vehicle. So "being a data scientist" could be correlated with "owning a Tesla" or whatever. Again, I don't have much of a stats background, perhaps I'm misunderstanding the core idea of a correlation here.

Comment: correlation is  computed between numeric variables. What exactly do you mean in this context?

Comment: It looks like you want a [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) (i.e. a [contingency table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table)).  Once you have that, you can use, for example, [`scipy.stats.chi2_contingency`](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chi2_contingency.html) to test for association among the categories.

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df['jobs'], df['cars'], normalize = True)` will that work?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser `crosstab` is exactly what I needed. Pretty slick, thank you!

Comment: just in case you are interested. if you want to use `diff` you could change those columns to type `category`. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51241909/15521392)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [crosstabs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html)

```
pd.crosstab(df['jobs'], df['cars'], normalize = True)
```