# How to calculate correlation on a specific dataset

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

my dataset

```
Rate Class
11.2 A
21.4 A
0.11 B
51.6 B
43.7 C
90.8 C
8.3  D 
14.4 D
```

I want to know the correlation with rate for each class.

```
A     B     C     D
11.2  Nan   Nan   Nan
21.4  Nan   Nan   Nan
Nan   0.11  Nan   Nan
Nan   51.6  Nan   Nan
Nan   Nan   43.7  Nan
Nan   Nan   90.8  Nan
Nan   Nan   Nan   8.3
Nan   Nan   Nan   14.4
```

I modified the dataset as follows but cannot find the corrleation due to the nan value.

Can you know how to find the correlation in this case?

Comment: do you mean the correlation between the different classes? as in correlation between A and B, B and C, etc?

Comment: @Roy2012 It refers to the correlation between rate and class. rate & A, rate & B, rate & C, rate & D.
I want to check the degree of influence on the rate of each class. Is my methodological approach wrong?

Comment: I'm familiar with correlation as a mathematical term that relates to two series of numbers. I'm not familiar with the notion of correlation between a class (which is a discrete thing) and a set of numbers - but I'm not necessarily an expert. There are classification algorithms, that given a rate will predict the class - but I don't think they are referred to as 'correlation'.

Comment: Why do each classes have two rates ? Could you find the mean or sum so as to find how each class correlates with rank.

Comment: @Roy2012 Thank you for the serious answer. In case of this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48873233/is-there-a-way-to-get-correlation-with-string-data-and-a-numerical-value-in-pand

There is a method, does this seem suitable for use here?

Comment: @Suraj Subramanian Well, for example, if 'Class' is a classroom in a school, it would be more convenient to understand that 'rate' is the rate of increase in grades by student. I want to find out if each classroom is related to the rate of increase in grades.

Comment: The problem is that you are looking to calculate a correlation between categorical and continuous numerical variables. Correlation is defined between numerical variables, so technically what you are after does not exists. However, [this post](https://medium.com/@outside2SDs/an-overview-of-correlation-measures-between-categorical-and-continuous-variables-4c7f85610365) does consider an alternative characteristics of mutual dependence for this situation.

Comment: @ybin, that link seems to be useful. I will look into it and try the same on your case. Thank you for your clarification.

Comment: @ybin - the question you refer to (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48873233/is-there-a-way-to-get-correlation-with-string-data-and-a-numerical-value-in-pand) does something similar - it translates a sentence to a vector of 0 and 1 - depending on which word appears in which sentence. This method won't really work here, because the classes are disjoint in your case.

Comment: @Roy2012 Thanks for the reply! I'll think more about this.