# Check column encodings in the pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame that contains two columns `name` and `name_id`. Column `name` contains strings (names of books) and column `name_id` contains integers.

I want to make a check that these two columns have direct correspondence and that in fact `name_id` is an encoding for `name`.

The trick is that `name_id` contains not consecutive numbers.

The only thing I came to so far is to make my own (consecutive) encodings for both of the columns and to check the correlation value on those. But what is a better/cleaner solution?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well, you could replace `name id`with your current index like this:

```py
df = (
    df.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=False)
    .drop(columns="name_id")
    .rename(columns={"index": "name_id"})
)

#  Output:
#  name_id  name
#        0  book a
#        1  book b
#        2  book c
```

Comment: yes, but my problem is that I do not know for sure that `name_id` is indeed simply encoded `name`. Perhaps it is not and it actually contains useful information. I probably could just glance through some values, but I was looking for something more reliable.

Comment: Then, I recommend that you check this post before getting rid of "name id": https://stackoverflow.com/a/48873546/11246056